# Get working days (Monday-Friday) and replace them with "between" in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some query in which I am substituting 2 dates in a field "between".

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE o.EventDate between @startDate and @endDate
```

How to make it so that only business days are processed in the request. That is, if I pass, for example, startDay = '04/14/2022' , endDay = '04/28/22', then only business days (Monday-Friday) would be processed in the request

Comment: What about national holidays?

Comment: What about other "nonwork" days - like when you have to close due to a hurricane evacuation or lockdown? An actual calendar is the only reliable solution.

Comment: @jarlh need only monday - friday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query which provides your expected output like date between the given date and week days from monday to friday:

```
SELECT columns 
FROM Table 
WHERE date_column between @startDate AND @endDate 
AND DATENAME(DW,date_column) not in ('Saturday','Sunday')
```

Comment: Yours is better !

Comment: Not really. It uses the abbreviation for the datepart - which saves a trivial amount of effort but makes the code more difficult to read. It also depends on a specific language.

Comment: agree with you concern.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query which provide your expected output like date between given date and week days from Monday to Friday
But some public holiday are not count in business days so for that you have to create master table which tells the public holidays which your organization consider out of business days and filter those days from your query

Here my query (SQL Server) consider first day of week is Sunday so range between 2-6 is used

```
SELECT columns FROM Table
WHERE date_column BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate 
AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date_column) BETWEEN 2 AND 6
```

Comment: Note that the SQL Server setting can be different, e.g. Monday can be set to be first day of week. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bfe7656ff70929a08ee4d434f18a59e3